# have_selector is too literal in rspec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Not sure what the issue here is as I have the same syntax in other tests.  I have a table, and I'm checking that content in is in the table header.  here's my test:

```
before(:each) do
  @index = get :index, id: @user, user_id: @user.id
end

it "should be successful" do
   @index
   response.should be_success
 end

it "should have the right title" do
   @index
   response.should have_selector('title', content: "All classes")
 end

it "should have an element for each class" do
   @index
   @student_groups.each do |student_group|
     response.should have_selector('th', content: student_group.name)
   end
end
```

Here's the response.body:

```
<th><a href="/classes.2">Class 2</a></th>
```

And here's the error autotest is throwing:

```
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('th', content: student_group.name)
   expected following output to contain a <th>class 2</th> tag
```

So why is this getting read so literally?  the `student_group.name` IS inside of the  tags...

Comment: The `href` and/or case sensitive?

Comment: case-sensitive. thanks!

Comment: Where did you find the `content` option to `have_selector()`?

Comment: not sure what you mean, @OldPro

Comment: I mean the only options I've seen documented for `have_selector` are `text`, `visible`, and `exact`.  Where did you read that `content` was an option?

Comment: I saw it used in the Michael Hartl rails tutorial - it's worked for me so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here should have been obvious:

The test was expecting:

```
<th>class 2</th>
```

And it was getting:

```
<th>Class 2</th>
```

So as [Narfanator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171916/narfanator) mentioned in the comments, the problem was that this is case sensitive.  Woops!